# chart is not generated

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js, linechart

With the following code I'm trying to plot data from `new.json` using D3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
   body { font: 10px sans-serif; }
   .axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: #000; shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
   .x.axis path { display: none; }
   .line { fill: none; stroke: steelblue; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
</style>
```

Please help to make the above code work
Thanks

Comment: what is ObjectId()... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `display:none;` in your css :

```
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

Your data is set out wrong. It should be set like this :

```
var thisData = [{

    "fit": 28.476,
    "upr": 30.232,
    "lwr": 26.721
  },
  {
    "fit": 28.888,
    "upr": 30.685,
    "lwr": 27.09
  },
  {
    "fit": 29.299,
    "upr": 31.145,
    "lwr": 27.453
  }
];
```

To edit this data you can do something like this :

```
var newDataArray = [];
for (var key in oldData) { //go through old data
  //console.log(key)
  if (oldData[key].fit) { //check if it has value, i.e not the id objet
    var thisData = {
      fit: oldData[key].fit,
      upr: oldData[key].upr,
      lwr: oldData[key].lwr,
    }
    newDataArray.push(thisData) //push to new data array
  }
}
```

Then use `newDataArray`in your D3 functions

Your data also has this line :

```
"_id": ObjectId("56dff08a85e64a6b39381485"),
```

I have made a function to counter this as Im not sure what it does :

```
function ObjectId(id) { //this is just to get round your id in your data
  return id
}
```

Basically just returns the string inside the bracks of the ObjectID.

At first I thought it was just displaying one line. But I hand edited the data to check.

Updated fiddle with generated data (edited): https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/v211r7ap/5/

The main things to note are the following :

You were returning 1 in the x domain, which would place all the lines on the same vertical line, return `i` to get equal distances between points :

```
x.domain(d3.extent(newDataArray, function(d, i) {
  return i;
}));
```

Same goes for the line :

```
.x(function(d,i) {
    console.log(d);
    return x(i);
  })
```

Finally to edit the ticks on either axis you edit the `tickFormat()`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i){
    return i //"Year1 Year2, etc depending on the tick value - 0,1,2,3,4"
});
```

Final fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/v211r7ap/7/

Comment: Im going to delete most of these comments makes it look messy. Btw, when you ask another question, copy the link here and ill take a look

Comment: @jos Of course it isn't, that is an array of objects whereas before it was an object of objects. In my code to make the data im looping through each object, you will have to change that to for(var key in oldData[0]){.... then it will work fine, as your data is basically an array of size one filled with objects. Understand ? Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/v211r7ap/8/

Comment: Thanks a lot bro:)